# Querying three tables at once SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need some help sorting out my queries, it's the first time I've run into the need to query three tables at once so I'm a little lost.

**The database looks like this:**

```
1[COMPANY]  --- <has> --- *[ACCOUNTS]1  --- <has> --- *[PAYMENTS]

Table COMPANY  has columns: CompID | CompanyName  |
Table ACCOUNTS has columns: AccID  | Name         | Company     |
Table PAYMENTS has columns: PayID  | GroupID      | PaymentDue  | DateDue
```

where Company references CompID and GroupID references AccID.

**I need to:**

1. Get ALL COMPANIES
2. Get the number of ACCOUNTS under a COMPANY
3. Total all the PAYMENTS of the ACCOUNTS in a COMPANY based on the closest date to the current date.

**This is how my display should look:**

```
 COMPANY      | No. of ACCOUNTS | TOTAL DUE        | DATE DUE 
 'Comp 1'     |       3         | 10000            | 4/30/2015            
 'Comp 2'     |       2         | 8000             | 4/30/2015
```

Doing this one by one is easy enough ( except the 3rd, I don't know how to get that done yet ) but getting them all in one go with so many conditions is confusing me. Can anyone give me a general idea of what a query for this case would look like?

**EDIT**

I only need to total the PAYMENTS with the date that is closest to the current date, anything that does not fall into "closest to current date" is irrelevant.

Also that I only need the closest UPCOMING dates, so anything before the current date is deemed irrelevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Company, COUNT(AccID), SUM(PaymentDue), MIN(DateDue)

FROM PAYMENTS JOIN ACCOUNTS
ON PAYMENTS.GroupID = ACCOUNTS.AccID 
JOIN COMPANY
ON ACCOUNTS.Company = COMPANY.CompID)

GROUP BY Company
```

I have not tested this code, but this should work with SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select      c.compid,
            ifnull(count(distinct a.accid),0) as num_accounts,
            ifnull(count(*),0) as num_payments
from        company c
  left join accounts a
         on c.compid = a.company
  left join (   select      p.*
                from        payments p
                       join (
                                select      groupid,
                                            min(datedue) as next_due
                                from        payments
                                where       datedue >= date('now');
                                group by    groupid
                            ) v
                         on p.groupid = v.groupid
                        and p.date_due = v.next_due
            ) v
         on p.groupid = v.groupid
group by    c.compid
```

Your third criterion wasn't entirely clear to me, when you say:
"Total all the PAYMENTS of the ACCOUNTS in a COMPANY based on the closest date to the current date."
I interpret this to mean you only want payments that are associated with the nearest `date_due` associated with each account (relative to the current date). In other words, no payments that were due before that such date, and no payments that were due after that such date.

Comment: My bad, didn't clear it up enough. But yes that is pretty much what I meant with that criterion. I only need to total the PAYMENTS with the date that is closest to the current date, anything that does not fall into "closest to current date" is irrelevant. I'll put this up in an edit.

Comment: Okay, in that case I think the above should work, if the result is different from what you expect please let me know how